# Looking through class Arraylist objects without nested loops

Tags: java, loops, oop, arraylist, nested-loops

I had this object oriented programming project last semester and it was all about simulating a simple dormitory.

1.There should have been a manager class in which the main method and like 80 percent of the other methods had to be there.
2.A dormitory class containing an arraylist of blocks.
3.A block class containing an arraylist of rooms.
4.A room class containing an arraylist of students.
5.All of these classes contained getters and setters for their private variables.

There were a few methods that we should've added to the program which has nothing to do with my question,so I will not write them in here,but the thing is,a few of theses methods needed to look through these arraylists to find a specific object.For example,a student with a specific student number.I created these methods with nested loops.But I know there is some way I could avoid heavy nesting.

Here is my reduced code.I will only let the manager class contain one nested loop method as an example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Manager {

    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;

    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Dormitory dorm = new Dormitory();
    private static Menu menu = new Menu();
    private Student tempStudent;
    private Block tempBlock;
    private Room room;
    private boolean bool;

    {
        dorm.setDormManager(this);
    }

    public Manager(String managerName, String managerID) {
        name = managerName;
        userName = managerID;
    }

    //find student with its number
    public void findStudent() {
        //Taking the student number from the user.
        System.out.println("Please enter the student number:");
        String studentNum = scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < dorm.getBlockList().size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < dorm.getBlockList().get(i).getRooms().size(); j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < dorm.getBlockList().get(i).getRooms().get(j).getRoomStudents().size(); k++)
                    if (dorm.getBlockList().get(i).getRooms().get(j).getRoomStudents().get(k).getStudentNumber().equals(studentNum)) {
                        tempStudent = dorm.getBlockList().get(i).getRooms().get(j).getRoomStudents().get(k);
                        break;
                    }
    }

    public void create() {
        //Used loops for the original program.
        Block block1 = new Block("1");
        Block block2 = new Block("2");
        dorm.getBlockList().add(block1);
        dorm.getBlockList().add(block2);
        Room room1 = new Room("1");
        Room room2 = new Room("2");
        dorm.getBlockList().get(0).getRooms().add(room1);
        dorm.getBlockList().get(1).getRooms().add(room2);
        Student student1 = new Student("12345678");
        Student student2 = new Student("98765432");
        dorm.getBlockList().get(0).getRooms().get(0).getRoomStudents().add(student1);
        dorm.getBlockList().get(1).getRooms().get(0).getRoomStudents().add(student2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager manager = new Manager("Dumbledore", "@1112");
        manager.create();
    }
}

public class Dormitory {

    private int blocks;
    private Manager dormManager;
    private long allMembers;
    private ArrayList<Block> blockList = new ArrayList<Block>();
}

public class Block {

    private String blockNumber;
    private ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
    private Dormitory dorm = new Dormitory();

    public Block(String blockNum) {
        blockNumber = blockNum;
    }
}

public class Room {

    private String roomNumber;
    private ArrayList<Student> roomStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
    private Block roomBlock;
    private Student roomManager;

    public Room(String roomNum) {
        roomNumber = roomNum;
    }
}

public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private String studentFamilyName;
    private String studentNumber;
    private Room room;

    public Student(String studentNum) { //Creates a student object using the student number.
        studentNumber = studentNum;
    }
}
```

I tried my best to reduce the code.
I searched a lot and asked a lot of people about this but I didn't get my desired answer.I'm not sure why I couldn't find anything about this,but I'd really appreciate it if you'd lend me a hand or give me the link of a related article.

Comment: Just a reminder: You cannot run Java code in snipplets

Comment: Please don't do redundant comments like "constructor" above a constructor or "variables" above variables. Comments should add details or clarification to code that can't document itself in some aspects.

Comment: Self-descriptive declarations, definitions or statements, do not need to be commented, unless it's *really necessary*. For example, in the definition `int x = 5; //assigning 5 to variable x`, the comment is really useless, it makes more noise, and the code would look ugly and difficult to read, if you keep writing these comments for several other code snippets. Remember, to keep your code as simple and as clean as possible.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nested loops.

Comment: Wow is my commenting really that bad?I'm sorry I was just trying to make it more readable.I guess I should see more examples of good commenting.Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you should never loop through everything checking for `getStudentNumber().equals(studentNum)`. This has [linear time complexity O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)

Long answer: You should index your data based on your queries

Eg: Indexing with HashMaps which have [constant time complexity O(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time). (Note: This code is not thread safe)

```
public class SchoolService {
    private Map<String, Student> studentsById = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Long, Dorm> dormsById = new HashMap<>();

    /// dormsByAreaCode is showing an example of an index which groups objects into lists
    private Map<String, List<Dorm>> dormsByAreaCode = new HashMap<>();

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
       if (studentsById.containsKey(student.getName()) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate student " + student.getName());
       }
       studentsById.put(student.getId(), student);
    }

    public Student getStudentById(String studentId) {
       Student student = studentsById.get(studentId);
       if (student == null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("No such student " + studentId);
       }
       return student;
    }

    public void addDorm(Dorm dorm) {
        // TODO: validation
        dormsById.put(dorm.getId(), dorm);
        List<Dorm> areaDorms = dormsByAreaCode.get(dorm.getAreaCode());
        if (areaDorms == null) {
            areaDorms = new ArrayList<>();
            dormsByAreaCode.put(dorm.getAreaCode(), areaDorms);
        }
        areaDorms.add(dorm);
    }

    public Dorm getDormById(long dormId) {
        Dorm dorm = dormsById.get(id);
        // TODO: validation
        return dorm;
    }

    public List<Dorm> getDormsByAreaCode(String areaCode) {
        List<Dorm> areaDorms = dormsByAreaCode.get(areaCode);
        // TODO: validation
        return areaDorms;
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: What if the student with that number is in another dorm?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that studentNumber is a unique identifier.

Comment: I didn't know you were pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

The following quote is from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm). This is the perfect use case of the `forEach` method from the `Stream` interface. The link I provided and further reading on Streams can help avoid repetitive code.

> Using collections framework in Java, a developer has to use loops and make repeated checks. Another concern is efficiency; as multi-core processors are available at ease, a Java developer has to write parallel code processing that can be pretty error-prone.

```
dorm.getBlockList().stream().forEach((b) -> {
    b.getRooms().stream().forEach((r) -> {
        ...
    })
});
```

You can also read about `parallelStream`s from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-stream-foreach).

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. OP is asking if the loops are required at all

Comment: I don't think so, is that? Why would he do cascaded loops in the first place? I think what OP wants is to get the student given the dorm and studentNumber in an efficient manner.

Comment: OP is a student studying programming so best to assume they've not had much experience and are open to better solutions. It's also safe to assume that studentNumber is a unique identifier for each student and has nothing to do with the block/room they are in (do you think your studentNumber would change if you changed dorms?)

Comment: I think the student succeded with the project. The only thing the OP is in need is an efficient solution. If the student succeded with the code he wrote for his assignment, if he had been expected to write code like that just to find student with a specific studentNumber, the right assumption is that there could be similar studentNumber s in different dorms. I don't think there exists a professor that doesn't correct this before giving a passing mark unless this is the required behavior, even if not efficient.

Comment: I'm giving up, you've obviously never heard of the concept of a student number. It's your unique ID, it's used to login, it's used at the library to borrow books, it's used for everything